# xquery select request regarding time or date

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I would like to ask how can I select only the nodes that meet some restriction about time using xquery

for example I have this xml

```
<SensorList>
    <Sensor>
      <SensorID>1</SensorID>
      <SensorFeature>vox</SensorFeature>
      <SensorTime>20:45:00</SensorTime>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor>
      <SensorID>4</SensorID>
      <SensorFeature>vox</SensorFeature>
      <SensorTime>14:00:00</SensorTime>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor>
      <SensorID>2</SensorID>
      <SensorFeature>ax</SensorFeature>
      <SensorTime>12:00:00</SensorTime>
    </Sensor>
  </SensorList>
```

and I want to select only the sensor nodes that have SensorTime value bigger than 15:00:00
Is that possible
If the time threshold corresponds to sensortime variable will the command be something like this?

```
doc('vagelisdb/CIDEM.xml')/SensorList/Sensor/SensorTime[SensorTime>'15:00:00']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your sensor time is a valid `xs:time` data type then you would need to adjust your XPath like so:

```
doc('vagelisdb/CIDEM.xml')/SensorList/Sensor[xs:time(SensorTime) gt xs:time("15:00:00")]
```

This will select the `sensor` nodes that match your time criteria. Note that in your examples you had `/SensorTime[SensorTime` which would imply that the element `SensorTime` has a child also called `SensorTime`; which does not match your example XML.

If you want to compare times then you need the `xs:time` constructor (or a cast) so that they are not compared as strings.

Comment: The nice thing with`xs:time` is that it is lexically ordered (the string values compare the same way as the typed values). So even if you compare the string values, you will get the same order (and in this case, the same filter).  Now, that being said, always use the typed value for comparison!

Comment: @FlorentGeorges That is true until you introduce timezones. Just mentioning for future readers of the question. e.g. 
`"15:00:00+06:00" gt "12:00:00"` is not the same as 
`xs:time("15:00:00+06:00") gt xs:time("12:00:00+01:00")`